# Iphone Map Application

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iPhone which displays a map view .I need to draw a polygon on the map view and get the details of that area.Looking for a solution..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could place a transparent `UIView` on top of your `MKMapView` instance.

Draw on your `UIView` using Quartz methods. See the [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuartzDemo/index.html) example for source code.

If you keep a 1:1 mapping between points drawn in your `UIView` and geographic coordinates in your `MKMapView` you should be able to do reverse geocoding and the like on areas of interest inside the polygon.